# Python "will the arrow fly straight program"

Tags: python

Want a program that used `windspeed` and target distance to determine if the arrow will hit the target. Got this far but not printing any results.

```
#Code starts here
#Will arrow hit target?
import random
from random import randint



windspeed = randint(1,5)
target_dist = randint(10, 100)


def effect_over_distance ():
    effect_over_distance = windspeed * target_dist
    if effect_over_distance < 100:
        chances = randint (1,3)
        return chances
    elif effect_over_distance > 100 < 200:
        chances = randint (1,10)
        return chances
    elif effect_over_distance >200 < 300:
        chances = randint (1,50)
        return chances

    else:
        chances = randint (1,50)
        return chances


print chances
```

Comment: Maybe `print effect_over_distance()` instead of `print chances` ?

Comment: You also don't need to `return chances` in every if/elif/else clause. Just do it once at the end of the function.

Comment: The `elif`s are wrong. If `effect_over_distance` is 300 then `effect_over_distance > 100 < 200` will be `True`. You need `100 < effect_over_distance < 200`. And maybe you want to use a `<=` because a value of 200 would lead you to the `else` part.

Answer (score 0):

You have a function that calculates the chances for you, from which you are returning the `chances` that you want (although you only have to use a single `return`). The variable `chances` is unknown to the main program so `print chances` should also produce a `NameError` as it's undefined.

You should call your function and assign the returned output to a variable as follows:

```
# import random <-- This is overkill as you only need randint which you import below
from random import randint

windspeed = randint(1,5)
target_dist = randint(10, 100)

def effect_over_distance ():
    effect_over_distance = windspeed * target_dist
    if effect_over_distance <= 100:
        chances = randint (1,3)
    elif effect_over_distance <= 200:
        chances = randint (1,10)
    elif effect_over_distance <= 300:
        chances = randint (1,50)
    else:
        chances = randint (1,50)
    return chances

foo = effect_over_distance()
print foo
```

Comment: Hey guys!! Thanks for all the help!! Still very fresh in this programming world but It's awesome to get such good advice. Still need to finish the code so that it displays a True or False if the value of effect_over_distance... Getting to that stage where it's becoming addictive.. haha